# Getting the next TimeStamped Result to tie to the prior result

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, window-functions

My table looks like this in BigQuery

```
+--------------------+------------+--------+--------+
|     TimeStamp      |  Session   |  Type  | Result |
+--------------------+------------+--------+--------+
| 7/28/2020 16:05:02 | 1595952288 | Select |  53402 |
| 7/28/2020 16:05:16 | 1595952288 | Menu   |      2 |
| 7/28/2020 16:05:25 | 1595952288 | Select |  53405 |
| 7/28/2020 16:05:36 | 1595952288 | Menu   |      1 |
+--------------------+------------+--------+--------+
```

I would like to be able to pull the data to look like the below

```
+--------------------+------------+--------+--------+---------+
|     TimeStamp      |  Session   |  Type  | Result | Confirm |
+--------------------+------------+--------+--------+---------+
| 7/28/2020 16:05:02 | 1595952288 | Select |  53402 |       2 |
| 7/28/2020 16:05:25 | 1595952288 | Select |  53405 |       1 |
+--------------------+------------+--------+--------+---------+
```

Basically, what the data is is a person is within a Session in an application, they are entering a 5 digit number, then they are asked to confirm it.

- The five-digit number will be under the Type = Select
- The 1 or 2 will be under the Type = Menu, 1 being it was confirmed, 2 being it was wrong and they want to re-enter the 5 digit number

I am trying to tie in the next line to the 5 digit number based on the next TimeStamp and bring it into the same line to report on it.

Here is the SQL I created, I don't think it is right as it produces duplicates. I think there is a better way and it's not very efficient. Actually, it might be just plain wrong.

```
Select DISTINCT 
table1.Session, 
table1.Result, 
subtable1.Confirm

FROM 
`googleBQ_table` as table1
Left Join (
Select 
Result as Confirm,
Session,
MAX(TimeStamp)


FROM 
`googleBQ_table` 

WHERE Type =  'Menu' and LENGTH(Result) < 2

group by 1,2) as sub_table1 on sub_table1.Session = table1.Session


WHERE
table1.Session = '1595952288' and LENGTH(table1.Result) = 5
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

> within a Session in an application, they are entering a 5 digit number, **then** they are asked to confirm it.

based on above - I assume that confirmation row is always after select row - so below does it

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT *, LEAD(result) OVER(confirmation) Confirm 
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
  WINDOW confirmation AS (PARTITION BY session ORDER BY TimeStamp)
) 
WHERE type = 'Select'
```

if applied to sample data from your question - result is

```
Row TimeStamp           Session     Type    Result  Confirm  
1   7/28/2020 16:05:02  1595952288  Select  53402   2    
2   7/28/2020 16:05:25  1595952288  Select  53405   1
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that "select" and "menu" rows properly interleave, you can use window functions:

```
select timestamp, session, type, result, lead_result confirm
from (
    select 
        t.*, 
        lead(case when type = 'Menu' then result end) 
            over(partition by session order by timestamp) lead_result
    from `googleBQ_table` t
) t
where type = 'Select'
```